# How to make html in HTML() widget selectable

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a flutter blog application, and i am using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) to render the blog HTML content, I want this content to be selectable, I know of the `SelectableText()` widget, but this cant be used to render HTML.

Anyone has an idea how I can make my HTML text selectable from mobile?

Answer (score 4):

Several hours ago, in [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) merged to master commit that solves this problem. Right not you can import plugin to your project like this:

```
flutter_html:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html.git
      ref: master
```

Maybe for the time you are reading this post, the last changes will be published to pub.dev

Then, use SelectableHtml instead of Html:

```
SelectableHtml(
  data: menuButton.content ?? "",
  style: {
    "body": Style(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    ),
  },
  onLinkTap: (link, renderContext, map, element) async {
    if (link != null && link.isNotEmpty) {
      await launch(link);
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: Not good, SelectableHtml doesn't support `customRender` and `onImageTap`, kinda makes it useless for rich html.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap it in `SelectionArea()`.

For example:

```
SelectionArea(
  child: Html(
    data: '<p>Some data</p>',
  ),
);
```

The rendered html content will now be selectable.

The `SelectableHtml()` widget suggested by other answers has shortcomings as stated in their own docs on pub.dev and did not work well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit - It is now possible without any workarounds. Use K.Amanov's answer.

I achieved this using [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) and [html2md](https://pub.dev/packages/html2md) packages. Not an ideal solution as markdown doesn't support all html tags.

```
import 'package:html2md/html2md.dart' as html2md;
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
...
...
MarkdownBody(
  selectable: true,
  data: html2md.convert(
    'Your HTML Text here',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Library `flutter_html:`

In code:

```
SelectableHtml(
     data: 'Your text with html tag',
);
```